# Which assembly contains AppBar C#?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I would to add a Bottom AppBar in C#. I don't know which assembly contains AppBar.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
   <AppBar>
   <AppBarButton Label="Okay" Icon="Accept" />
   </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   XLS0414 The type 'AppBar' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  Programm70  MainWindow.xaml 12

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, while your question is warranted, we expect users to perform research before posting here (asking a Question on SO should be the last thing you do trying to solve a problem). I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar) by googling "c# AppBar"

Comment: XLS0414 is a Xamarin error message, AppBar is a UWP class.  You can't mix.  Google "xamarin appbar" to get possibly useful hits, if you see CommandBar then you're getting close.